# How to communicate from ViewModel to View

Tags: mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have a property on my ViewModel called LostFocus, and I want the View to know when this changes so that it can act on this info if it pleases (i.e. maybe the designer of the view might make it blur if LostFocus is set to true, or maybe they won't do anything).

I'm using Caliburn.Micro, so if it has any features I should be aware of here please do tell.  Otherwise, how would you go about doing this in an MVVM fashion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up learning about the BindingConverter and used that to convert a boolean property of false to null and true to a BlurEffect.

Comment: Cool, it's always good to give the designer some flexibility on the viewmodel you are providing, but to be honest you can get away with not providing a hell of a lot since `ValueConverters` are so useful. To be honest though, `LostFocus` sounds more like a design concern and not something your VM should be handling, though it would make perfect sense if your VM is modelling a custom control or something of that nature

Comment: @Charleh I have a mechanism that will let plugins display a window if they want, and if they do I just wanted the main window to blur.  Ultimately, I realized I didn't need the LostFocus property though since I have a ContentControl named PluginContent, and so I just bind to that and my value converter just checks to see if it's null or not.

Comment: There's always a way with bindings :)

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished with ordinary data binding as I understand it. Since you're using Caliburn.Micro, the designer can use conventions to do the binding. For example, if there were a check box control on the view that was to be checked when LostFocus is set to true, the designer would just have to ensure that the Name property of the check box was set to LostFocus and then Caliburn would set up the binding automatically.

Also, on your View Model, make sure you raise the property changed notification event when you change the value of LostFocus.

You could also, rather than using a LostFocus property, create a LostFocus event on your view model. You could then raise this event whenever you feel it's appropriate and then, on the view, the designer could respond to that using an event trigger and trigger action. For example, on one of my projects, I set up an event trigger to respond to the view model's Activated event and then I wrote a custom trigger action to play a storyboard that was responsible for doing the view's intro animation. This approach isn't restricted to Caliburn.Micro, but I did use it on a Caliburn.Micro project, so it definitely works.

Comment: I thought about that, but how to do it when I don't have a specific control like a CheckBox to tie it to?  I thought about just having an invisible control and I may do that if necessary, but it just rubs my idealistic side the wrong way you know.

Comment: Well, there are a couple of ways you could approach this: first, you could make your own convention if you have a custom control that you're binding or second, you could just use regular WPF (non-convention-based) binding.

Comment: Right, I get that but I guess the thing I'm hung on is that it seems odd to add a visual element I don't need to the view.  I'm wondering whether it makes more sense just to define an interface with an event and implement it on my ViewModel, and have the view subscribe to it.

Comment: Sure. It ultimately depends on how you envision the designer will implement the blur effect you talked about. They could create another visual element that represents the blur effect and then bind its visibility property to LostFocus on your view model (using a converter to convert Boolean to Visibility). Or like you said, you could raise an event that they could subscribe to and run storyboard or something.

Comment: I ended up taking another route as you can see from the answer I just added, but +1 for the good thoughts.